# $\dim H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(n)) = ?$ for genus $g$ Riemann surface $X$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, projective-space

Suppose that $X = \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$, a Riemann surface of genus $g = 0$, then for $n \geq 0$
\begin{equation}
\dim_\mathbb{C} H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(n)) = n+1, \qquad \dim_\mathbb{C} H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(-n)) = 0.
\end{equation}
What if $X$ has genus $g > 0$? I guess $\dim_\mathbb{C} H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(-n)) = 0$ is still true since $\mathcal{O}(-n)$ has negative degree, hence no global section. But how do I find $\dim_\mathbb{C} H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(n))$?

What if $X$ is some arbitrary projective varieties, can I find $\dim_\mathbb{C} H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(n))$ in general?

Comment: Do you know Riemann-Roch formula ?

Comment: I tried to use that but I don't know how to continue from $l(n) - l(K - n) = -n + 1 - g$. Basically what is $l(K - n)$?

Comment: I don't know if you can have an exact answer, it might depends on the curve. But surely for $n$ big enough $l(K-n) = 0$ by degree consideration so the asymptotic formula is $l(n) = n + 1 - g$.

Comment: You can find a formula for [Asymptotic Riemann-Roch here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=jAWVmIz80A4C&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=asymptotic+riemann+roch&source=bl&ots=AK2eMFvlI7&sig=WxyQo9N72Idc0TV4YnV5DI92V3E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOgJaoq4TWAhWKKo8KHf6pBvcQ6AEITTAL#v=onepage&q=asymptotic%20riemann%20roch&f=false) This is what @N.H. said.

Comment: First of all, when $g > 0$ you need to be careful with what you mean by $\mathcal O(1)$; the implication here would be that you have a fixed projective embedding, but without that data, the notation doesn't make sense since higher genus curves have larger Picard rank. Regarding the computation for an arbitrary projective variety, I will just quote my advisor who once described the general question there as being as complex as "all of linear algebra."

Comment: @TabesBridges I was thinking of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ as the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(p_1 + ... + p_n)$ corresponding to divisor class of $n$ points $p_1 + ... + p_n \in A_0(X)$ on $X$. When $g = 0$ all points are linearly equivalent, I guess this is not true for $g > 0$? And what you are saying is different classes in $A_0(X)$ would give a line bundle corresponding to a different projective embedding? Is that sort of correct?

Comment: @user113988 Exactly. A couple of simple examples come to mind (also, I'm going to discuss some maps which are not embeddings): first, consider the sum of two points on a hyperelliptic curve. If these are two random points, you get a very different divisor than if these are hyperelliptic-conjugate points. Another case would be the canonical class, which is the unique divisor class of degree $2g - 2$ which has $g$ sections; all others have $g - 1$...

Comment: ...The reason for this (looking at Riemann-Roch) is the more fundamental "Serre dual" fact that the trivial divisor class is the only degree $0$ class with a section. And when $g=2$, my first example with the hyperelliptic divisor coincides with the canonical divisor.

Comment: @TabesBridges Could you explain a bit more about hyperelliptic curve example? Suppose we have a curve $\Sigma:y^2 - P(x) = 0$, then by hyperelliptic conjugation you mean $y \rightarrow -y$, right? Let's say I construct $\Sigma$ by gluing two $\mathbb{C}$ sheets ($+y$ and $-y$ sheets). Then $[(+y,x)] + [(-y,x)] \neq [p_1] + [p_2]$ if $p_1, p_2$ are on the same sheet? How could I show this? I tried to argue that there's no function $f:\Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f^{-1}(\infty) = \{(-y,x),(+y,x)\}$ with zeros on the same sheet, but I'm not too sure why this is true.

Comment: @user113988 Do you know the notion of a complete linear system? This is just a linear system which is the *full* $H^0$ of some line bundle, not a proper subspace. On a hyperelliptic curve $C$ (of any genus), the hyperelliptic map is given by $|H^0(\omega_C)|$. Since this linear system is complete, *all* divisors in the linear equivalence class $|f^{-1}(\infty)|$ arise as fibers $f^{-1}(p)$. Since the sum of two points in the same sheet does not arise as a fiber of $f$, we have the desired nonequivalence.

Comment: @TabesBridges Hyperelliptic map is the double cover $f : C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$? So do we have $[f^{-1}(0)] - [f^{-1}(\infty)] = \omega_C$ (pretty sure this is wrong since the l.h.s. should be 0)? Therefore the entire equivalence class of $[(+y,x)] + [(-y,x)]$ must be in the fiber of $f$ but the sum of two points on the same sheet isn't? I guess the only part I don't really understand is the relationship between $f$ and the linear system of $\omega_C$. Could you expand that a bit if you don't mind, thank you.

Comment: @user113988 what is your background? This relationship should be covered in any basic text on curves or varieties; in any case, for $g=2$ we have $h^0(\omega_C) = 2$; let $\mu,\lambda$ be a basis. You map $p \in C$ to $(s:t) \in \mathbb P^1$ iff the linear combination $s\mu + t\lambda$ (which remember is a $1$-form) vanishes at $p$. In the hyperelliptic case, if $p$ kills a linear combination of $1$-forms, so will its conjugate, but no other point....

Comment: ... When $g > 2$, we have a similar double covering situation, but there are more $1$-forms on $C$ and the image $\mathbb P^1$ is a rational normal curve in $\mathbb P^{g-1}$.

Comment: @TabesBridges I think that makes sense. Thanks for your help. My background is in physics so I tend to ask a lot of easy questions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. I have posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400104/cohomology-of-the-pullback-of-a-sheaf) question, which deals with compact riemann surface embedded in some $\mathbb{P}^n$, and the answer to the question says that the global sections of $O(1)=i^{*}O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ cannot be determined in general since the pullback map can be anything, in fact $dim H^0(X,O(1))=n+1$ in the case a variety is linearly normal and not all varieties are (see the answer to my post).